# textbox can't get focus in Node.js

Tags: node.js, textbox, coffeescript, pug

I have a textbox in my site that can't seem to get focus. I tried adding focus on click with jQuery but that seems to have no effect. Can anyone help me out?

App link: http://test-app-andrew.herokuapp.com/

Jade:

```
div(id="templates",class="sideBarContent")
    div(id="addPageBox")
        input(type="text",id="addPage")
```

HTML(output from above):

```
<div id="templates" class="sideBarContent">
  <div id="addPageBox">
    <input type="text" id="addPage">
  </div>
</div>
```

Coffeescript:

```
$ ->
 $('input#addPage').click ->
    $('input#addPage').focus()
```

Javascript (output from above):

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.8.0
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('input#addPage').click(function() {
      return $('input#addPage').focus();
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: It's the `zindex` of `-1` on `div#sidebar` that's your problem. This is stacking the input below your `wrapper div`